# How to have git output only files related to an issue?

Tags: git

Our commit messages are formatted like this:
`PROJECT_NAME-ISSUE_NUM commit msg.`

Question: How can I search for files that were changed by developer working on specific issue?

Note that I need only file names. For the purpose of this question, I don't care for commit messages, diff or anything else. Filenames. Once.

Shell script is ok.

Things that got me the closest:

- `git log --name-status --one-line --grep ISSUE_NUM`
  I get commit messages I don't care about and same file is included multiple times, if it was changed in multiple commits.
- `git diff origin/master...HEAD --name-status --grep ISSUE_NUM`
  Seems to include all files that differ between origin/master and current branch, not only the ones that were changed by developer working on that specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do a string filter on a diff, along the lines of :

```
git diff --name-only origin/master...HEAD -S"ISSUE_NUM"
```

You can check [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) for details, or variants with regular expressions if need arises.

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution is nearly correct, but you're getting the subject of the commit message with --oneline.  You want a less verbose format, such as an empty string.  Just pipe the output to `sort -u` to remove duplicates:

```
git log --name-only --format='' --grep "${ISSUE_NUM?}" | sort -u
```

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of --format option! I'm leaving the question without accepted answers for 24h, but now I ended up adding this to my .gitconfig :)

Comment: Just for completeness, I've added
`ls-related = !sh -c 'git log --name-status --format="" --grep $1 | sort -u' -`
as an git alias